# XML remove nil attribute

Tags: c#, xml, nullable, null

I am doing some XmlOverrides and setting properties to nullable (F1 in this case). I would want to delete nil="true" and the namespace around this attribute, but I can't remove it with any method I've tried.

```
Nested n = new Nested();
n.Nest = "2";
n.F1 = null;

XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();

XmlAttributes att = new XmlAttributes();
XmlElementAttribute el = new XmlElementAttribute("F1");
el.IsNullable = true;
att.XmlElements.Add(el);
overrides.Add(typeof(Nested), "F1", att);

XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Nested), overrides);

var faultDocument = new XmlDocument();
var nav = faultDocument.CreateNavigator();
var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("", "");

using (var writer = nav.AppendChild())
{
    xs.Serialize(writer, n, ns);
}
```

XML I get is like this:

```
<Nested>
    <F1 p2:nil="true" xmlns:p2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
    <Nest>2</Nest>
</Nested>
```

But I would want that F1 element be empty, without nil and xmlns

```
<Nested>
    <F1/>
    <Nest>2</Nest>
</Nested>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in Nested class `[XmlElement(ElementName = "F1", IsNullable = true)]` in property F1.

Comment: Can't do that, I can't change properties due to various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it, not sure if it's the best way to do it:

```
private static void RemoveNils(XElement elem)
{
        string nilNamespace = "{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}nil";
        //first condition should be enough, the rest are just fail-safes
        if (elem.Attributes().Any(name => name.Name == nilNamespace) && elem.Elements().Count() == 0 && elem.IsEmpty)
        {
            elem.Attributes().Remove();
            return;
        }

        foreach (XElement el in elem.Elements())
            RemoveNils(el);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Nested n = new Nested();
n.Nest = "2";
n.F1 = null;

XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();

XmlAttributes att = new XmlAttributes();
XmlElementAttribute el = new XmlElementAttribute("F1");
el.IsNullable = true;
att.XmlElements.Add(el);
overrides.Add(typeof(Nested), "F1", att);

XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Nested));

var faultDocument = new XmlDocument();
var nav = faultDocument.CreateNavigator();
StringWriter strWriter = new StringWriter();
XmlTextWriter TextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(strWriter);
var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("", "");
xs.Serialize(TextWriter, n, ns);
ReqXml = strWriter.ToString();
TextWriter.Close();
return ReqXml;
```